# VB.NET : How to write to a PlaceHolder in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I am new to MVC.

I have a string that I built from a controller called parsedCustomerNames. In web forms I can make the placeholder visible from the codebehind and then populate a control with the string.

How would I be able to do this in MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe parsedCustomerNames is a coma separated list of customers (As opposed to a collection). You can do it like this in ASP.NET MVC:

Suppose, following is your controller:

```
public class HomeController : Conroller{
   public ActionResult Index(){
      ViewData["ParsedCustomerNames"] = parsedCustomerNames; //Get the string here.
      return View();
   }
}
```

And then inside your view, do the following:

```
<div class="customerName">
   <%: ViewData["ParsedCustomerNames"] as string %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you don't need placeholder as such.

Place this logic of showing this string inside a "Div". If you have anything in string, div will appear otherwise it will be as good as invisible.

Another thing to focus is that Asp.Net MVC is not event driven as normal Asp.Net is. You need to think in terms of Get and Post. Everything you do in Asp.Net MVC will be a result of user action which will be Get/Post. Every action will provide some data (M of MVC) to your view and you will have to redraw your page (v of MVC). If you have any data on particular "div" then it will appear automatically otherwise not.